# Hair children don't seem to respond to changes?

Tags: particles, hair, interpolation

I'm trying to style hair for a character, mainly following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KpVyTc_72z0&t=22s), but encountered a weird issue.
Not only children hair looks all scattered instead of being in a clean line, but it also looks like they don't seem to respond to any change I make in the hair particle settings tab.
I tried changing any number, value or slider, but nothing changes in the viewport... Any help?

Here's a screenshot of the mess:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Particle systems still seem to be a little buggy sometimes. I recently had a similar problem. The way to "fix" this is to press G to move the object and then hit ESC or rightclick to cancel the transform. That way it snaps back to its position before and the particles update. While this might be a possible workaround, there might be a better solution because obiously an instant update would be a lot more convenient.